# GREP for a timestamp within parentheses

Tags: grep

I need to create a GREP to search a doc for timestamps.  However, these timestamps are in parentheses.

Ex. (23:54) or (02:03) etc.

The numbers within the parentheses vary and I need to find them all.

Here's what I was using in the past for timestamps:
[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]

However, this will not select the parentheses and if I add parentheses on to this, it does nothing.

I also tried /([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).  But that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Also, sometimes the timestamps are 6 numbers so (02:21:54).  So, I need to search these as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### I need to create a GREP to search a doc for timestamps

> Ex. (23:54) or (02:03) etc.
>
> Also, sometimes the timestamps are 6 numbers so (02:21:54)

Use the following regular expression:

```
\([0-9]+:[0-9]+\)|\([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\)
```

Tested at [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

Since I cannot add comments to foreign questions/answers yet, I'll add some additions and background to [DavidPostills](https://superuser.com/a/1557942/1183051) answer via an own answer. This is based on my knowledge/experience with `grep` in Debian-based Linux distributions and derivatives, hence I cannot assure that all is valid in detail on other `grep` implementations/builds as well.

#### Background

The issue with the parenthesis most likely is that they are magic characters themselves in extended regular expressions for grouping patterns, which practically has no effect in this case. The linked answer solves this by escaping the parenthesis via backslash to force them being interpreted literally, so usually this will work.

However at least on Debian (Wheezy+) and Ubuntu (Xenial+), extended regular expressions are not enabled by default in `grep`. It needs to be enabled explicitly via option [`-E`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/grep/grep.1.en.html#Matcher_Selection).
Depending on the particular grep defaults, it might be the other way round, so that one might want to disable *extended* regular expressions explicitly instead via option `-G`. In your case that would allow you to use the regex you tried to catch the parenthesis:

```
grep -G '([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])' /path/to/doc
```

However the downside of only basic regular expressions is that the special meaning of `|` *(`alternative1|alternative2`)*, `?` *(previous character/group might or might not be present)* and `+` *(previous character/group is present one or more times)* and some other fancy stuff is lost, hence the beauty of the regex of DavidPostill to allow one or more digits and make either hours or seconds optional will not work anymore.

But extended regex special characters can be re-enabled by escaping them again via backslash. So with only basic regex enabled, DavidPostills pattern is broken in two ways:

- `+` and `|` are taken literally.
- `\(` and `\)` are interpreted as extended regex special characters to group their enclosed pattern, which practically has no effect in this case.

#### Solutions

So depending on whether `grep` interprets the pattern as either basic or extended regular expression, either due to defaults or explicit choice for some reason, the following solutions will work:

Basic regex with per-char/group extended regex enabled via backslash:

```
grep -G '([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\(:[0-9][0-9]\)\?)' /path/to/doc

# Using extended regex "{2}" for "previous char/group two times"
#  which has the exact same meaning and regex length as above:
grep -G '([0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\(:[0-9]\{2\}\)\?)' /path/to/doc

# Less specific, allowing "(7:24:13)" but also "(3432:0054:1)"
grep -G '([0-9]\+:[0-9]\+\(:[0-9]\+\)\?)' /path/to/doc
```

Extended regex:

```
grep -E '\([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2})?\)' /path/to/doc

# Less specific, allowing "(7:24:13)" but also "(3432:0054:1)"
grep -E '\([0-9]+:[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?\)' /path/to/doc
```